# Hibernate session.beginTransaction() call and Mysql Start Transaction

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

When I issue the command

```
session.beginTransaction();
// do something
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I don't see a corresponding Start Transaction command issue to my database. Can any body explain to why it is not there and how mysql knows the boundary of a transaction.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you use mysql InnoDB and the correct hibernate mysql InnoDB dialect too? And does `do something` contains database relevenat statements (load/update)?

Comment: Yes, i am using InnoDB and InnoDB dialect with mysql version 5.0

Answer (score 1):

As briefly mentioned in the [Hibernate Developer Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e565), JDBC does not define an explicit method for beginning a transaction. The [Java JDBC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) mentions disabling auto-commit mode to be able to group two or more statements into a transaction. This is exactly what Hibernate does in the `session.beginTransaction()` call.