# Hibernate transaction and 'for update'

Tags: mysql, hibernate, transactions, locking

I'm trying to obtain the lock on some rows on my mysql database using the "for update" statement. To do that I create a Criteria in the middle of an Hibernate Transaction and set a lock on it.

```
crit = session.createCriteria(AppIosVersion.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("version", version))
                .setLockMode(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

Using setLockMode the query is correctly sent to the database, this is what I see in mysql.log:

```
     133 Query  SET autocommit=0
          133 Query SET autocommit=1
          133 Query SET autocommit=0
          133 Query select this_.Version as Version1_5_0_, this_.EditTimeStamp as EditTime2_5_0_, this_.IsActive as IsActive3_5_0_ from AppAndroidVersion this_ where this_.Version='0.2' for update
130703 16:46:03   133 Query rollback
          133 Query SET autocommit=1
```

The problem is that the *for update* statement doesn't allow to acquire the lock because hibernate beginTransaction() doesn't become *START TRANSACTION* in mysql.

My hibernate configuration is the following (i'm not using Spring).

```
 <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>


   <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Versions?autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="connection.username">name</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    <!-- Session properties -->
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property> --> 
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>

    <!-- configuration pool via c3p0-->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">180</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">180</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Comment: It's pretty much the same question in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019983/hibernate-session-begintransaction-call-and-mysql-start-transaction

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use declarative transaction management provided by container like Spring, you have to explicitly deal with the transaction.

One simple way is to implement a [TransactionTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) like Spring does.

BTW, be careful to use statement like 'select xxx for update', make sure you release the lock properly and no other transaction will touch the locked rows.